# How to hold the shape when i rotate a texture through matrix using OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es

This is my VertexShader:

```
public static final String vs_Face =
                        "uniform mat4 transMatrix;" +
                        "uniform mat4 scaleMatrix;" +
                        "uniform mat4 rotateZMatrix;" +
                        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                        "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;" +
                        "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
                        "void main() {" +
                        "  gl_Position = transMatrix * rotateZMatrix *scaleMatrix *  vec4(vPosition.xyz,1.0) ;" +
                        "  v_texCoord = a_texCoord.xy;" +
                        "}";
```

This my FragmentShader:

```
public static final String fs_Face =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
                    "uniform sampler2D s_texture;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );" +
                    "}";
```

This is my Draw function

```
 GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE,GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        //
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramMagic);


        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mGLCubeId[0]);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandleFace);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandleFace, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mMagicTextureCoordinateId[0]);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLocFace );
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTexCoordLocFace, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,  4 * 2, 0);

        //control matrix
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mTransHandle,1,false,transMatrix,0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mScaleHandle,1,false,scaleMatrix,0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMvpMatrixHandle,1,false,mvpMatrix,0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mRotateZHandle,1,false,rotateZMatrix,0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mTransZeroMatrixHandle, 1, false, mTransZeroMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,mTextures[0]);
        if(i>=mTotalCount)
        {
            i=i-mTotalCount;
        }
        // update texture
        if(mPathList.size()-1>=i&&mTextureMap.containsKey(mPathList.get(i)))
        {
            GLUtils.texSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,mTextureMap.get(mPathList.get(i)));
        }

        GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLocFace, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandleFace);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLocFace);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
```

If I dont add the rotateZ matrix like this: `gl_Position =vec4(vPosition.xyz,1.0)` ,the texture can display properly. but after i add the rotateZMatrix,its shape will change.
This is the picture after i rotate 45 degrees,the rabbit ears and noise is the texture:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjFKC.jpg)

I don't know what i did wrong,I have tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Please modify this question. It is completely unclear what you are asking. Explain what you are trying to do; explain what is the desired result; explain what exactly is your current result (from the image we can only guess); add what you suspect the issue is and why; add what have you tried but did not work and why...

Comment: @MaticOblak Sorry, I try to upload 3 pictures, but limited by my reputation. Now, when I rotate the Texture around the Z axis , its shape will change. if I rotate a rectangle , it will become a parallelogram, width and height are changed. like the picture, the rabbit's noise has been sqeezed and stretched,  I want it keep its original shape without distortion when I rotate it.

Comment: I see. Well this is most likely the problem with how you combine those matrices. It might help to get some info on what are the values in those matrices transMatrix, scaleMatrix and rotateZMatrix when the issues start. But the better info would be if you (for debugging) changed the fragment shader to output a solid color so you could see how exactly does the shape deform. It probably stays a rectangle but is stretched and rotated. Have you tried changing the order of matrix multiplication in vertex shader? Note that order matters when multiplying matrices!

Comment: @MaticOblak I had tried to remove other matrixs, like this  `gl_Position =  rotateZMatrix  *  vec4(vPosition.xyz,1.0) ;` but the problem still persists, and I will try it based on your suggestions, thank you